# Why is 90 degrees the standard for independence in vectors?

Tags: vectors, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Why do so many laws and ideas in physics act separately if they are separated by 90 degrees?

Say you have a force in one direction, ***x***. You can't add a force within 0-90  degrees without changing the net force in the ***x*** direction. But if you add a force exactly 90 degrees away then the ***x*** component doesn't change, although the net force does.

What about 90 degrees makes things act independently of each other? Forces, conservation laws, etc.

Is this purely convention. If so, why?

Or does it have to do with something in nature?

Comment: Are you asking why why number $90$ is involved, or is the question something else?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the *orthonormality* of the basis for an *inner product space* whose vectors are *orthonormal.* For this reason, any vector of such space can be represented as a combination of two independent components.

Comment: I think I kind of get what you are saying. Are you saying it is just convention then? We are just using a system where things can be described by orthogonal components, so those components must be independent?

Comment: There is no convention in this, it is an observation about the nature of multiple dimensional space. Moving perpendicularly to a line simple doesn't move you along the line in either direction. What more do you want there to be?

Comment: That's a good way to think about it. Start with just pure motion and build from there into forces. Thanks dmckee! Though, I think you meant to say "simply".

Comment: I should have used easier words, I think. But dmckee is actually explaining it in the most easy way which I like.

Answer (score 0):

Also analytically if you break the force vector into two perpendicular directions the cos 90degree component will automatically become zero. For eg if a force f is acting in the x direction its component along the y axis i.e. f cos90 = 0 and along the x axis f sin90 = f.